# How to customize authz.py file in CKAN extension?

Tags: python, ckan

I want to add new role in CKAN. And I can do this in authz.py file. I defined a new role and give some action to the role and it worked. But i did this in baseline. I want to do this in extension. So i created new extension that named "customroles". And i copied the authz.py from "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan" to the custom folder "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-customroles/ckanext/customroles". Then i added new role(Super) as you can see below code.

```
ROLE_PERMISSIONS = OrderedDict([
    ('admin', ['admin']),
    ('editor', ['read', 'delete_dataset', 'create_dataset', 'update_dataset', 'manage_group']),
    ('member', ['read', 'manage_group']),
    **('super', ['read', 'delete_dataset', 'create_dataset', 'manage_group']),**
])


def _trans_role_admin():
    return _('Admin')


def _trans_role_editor():
    return _('Editor')


def _trans_role_member():
    return _('Member')

def _trans_role_super():
    return _('Super')
```

But I couldn't see the new role while i am adding the new member in organization page. When i modify the base code, i saw the new role. But in extension it did not work.

Do i need to do anything else to modify authz.py file in extension? Do you know how can i solve this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is currently not possible in an extension.

There are some parts of CKAN's authorization architecture that can be modified and extended via plugins, for example via the [`IAuthFunctions`](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IAuthFunctions), [`IAuthenticator`](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IAuthenticator), and [`IPermissionLabels`](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IPermissionLabels) interfaces. The roles in `ckan.authz`, however, are hard-coded.

You could try to use `IAuthFunctions` to override CKAN's built-in auth functions to create a similar effect. In particular, you could use that approach to remove some privileges from certain `editor` members, making them into the "super" users that you're trying to implement. (Note that *adding* privileges to `member` users will probably *not* work, since those users will fail the checks based on their role even if your modified auth functions would grant them access)

It won't solve your immediate problem, but I do think that it would be nice for CKAN to support what you're trying to do. I've therefore created [a ticket](https://github.com/ckan/ideas-and-roadmap/issues/223) in CKAN's feature-discussion-tracker. Feel free to add further information about your use case to it.

Comment: Super user and its privileges was just example. It is not that i want to create. I want to create different roles with different permissions. So changing current role's permission is not proper for me. I need to add new roles. 
And also i added new privileges to the member in base code(authz.py) and it worked.

Comment: I see. In that case you'll either need to run a patched version of CKAN or work towards support in CKAN for modifying authz via plugins.